# how to align div containers and table

Tags: html, css, widget, containers

I have been trying to layout my table and div containers in a certain way.

so div containers on the right (each container under each other) the table next to the containers and everything in centred.  I have tried using align: right but it doesn't work.  Not sure what else I can do.

```
 <div  style="width: 20%; ">           
        <table class="table table-bordered" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Created/Placed</th>
                <th>Req./Actual Delivery Date</th>
                <th>Supplier</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="widget" class="well well-large" style="width: 20%">
            <ul>
                <br>
                <li> orders</li>
                <li> orders</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="well well-large" style=" width:20%">
        <ul>
            <br>
            <li> orders</li>
            <li> orders</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-large" style=" width:20%">
        <ul>
            <br>
            <li> orders</li>
            <li> orders</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you should add your css to question

Comment: I don't have css, I just added style="" to the html.  I know its  not the correct way to do it but this is just me trying to figure out the layout

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Comment: A very basic thing you can do is use `float: left` to get the divs to all try to go left and stack on top of each other.  You should also check out any `padding` or `margins` as this could take up a bit of extra space and move things to the next line unintentionally

Comment: you have a `</div>` added at the end of the code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float left` for div `width 20%`, it worked with normal browser not code snippet.

```
div{
float:left;
}
```

```css
div{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div  style="width: 20%; ">           
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Created/Placed</th>
                <th>Req./Actual Delivery Date</th>
                <th>Supplier</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="widget" class="well well-large" style="width: 20%">
            <ul>
                <br>
                <li> orders</li>
                <li> orders</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="well well-large" style=" width:20%">
        <ul>
            <br>
            <li> orders</li>
            <li> orders</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-large" style=" width:20%">
        <ul>
            <br>
            <li> orders</li>
            <li> orders</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```